# ReactJS - Internet Explorer prompting stay/leave page on every refresh

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, reload, prompt, page-refresh

Every time I reload the page in IE 11 or hotreload is triggered after saving changes in code, IE prompts me with pop up stay/leave on this site. 
Chrome and Firefox work fine.

This started to happen from one day to another day. I don't know what I have changed that caused this bug.
Any clue what could be the problem ?

I have a ReactJS web application with redux and router.

Edit: FIX - looked for 'unload' in code and found

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
```

I deleted preventDefault() and now it works fine.
At first i was looking exactly for 'onbeforeunload' so that's why I could find anything.

Comment: can you add some code please? thanks

Comment: @tudor.gergely i don't know which part of code would help you and its not my personal project. Its client protected data. But if you have any tip where to look in the app then maybe i can post some code. As i said, i dont have a clue what caused this problem and its only for IE

Comment: do you have a part of your code where you do that prompt?

Comment: fixed it. I will post edit/update in original post. Basically now i didn't look for onbeforeunload but just for unload and that eventListener has e.preventDefault() in it. I deleted it and now it works fine

Comment: It's so glad that you have solved the issue. You could post the solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION - FIX - 
At first, I was looking exactly for 'onbeforeunload' so that's why I could find anything.
Then I looked for 'unload' in code and found

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
```

I deleted preventDefault() and now it works fine.